# Radio buttons with same name as array

Tags: php, html, input

I have a form that generates a list of items and I want to be able to give to each item a score from 1-5. Each item represents a db insert in one table, that is linked through the same id in another table. I need to have all radio buttons with the same name. I researched a bit and I found out that you can name them as an array. My issue is that the number of items the form table has varies, depending on the Group from which wish to submit the report, and I can't make the names assume different indexes depending on the item, score[0], score[1], etc.

HTML

```
<tr>
    <th>Indicador</th>
    <th>Peso</th>
    <th>Avaliação</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($indicators as $indicator): ?>
    <?php echo "<tr>
        <td>". $indicator->indicator_name ."</td>
        <td>". $indicator->weight*100 ."%</td>
        <td>
            <label>
                1 <input value='1' name='score[]' type='radio'>
            </label>
            <label>
                2 <input value='2' name='score[]' type='radio'>
            </label>
            <label>
                3 <input value='3' name='score[]' type='radio'>
            </label>
            <label>
                4 <input value='4' name='score[]' type='radio'>
            </label>
            <label>
                5 <input value='5' name='score[]' type='radio'>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>";

?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can probably tell already, every time I click on a radio button for a different item, the previous item gets unselected. How would I go about achieving this? Also any alternative solutions are appreciated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: increment the radio button every time.   `score".$i.".[]`, increment $i each round

Comment: Yes your solution works as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set inside the array the id of the item (`$indicator`).

If we assume that id is `$indicator->id` your code can be like this:

```
<tr>
<th>Indicador</th>
<th>Peso</th>
<th>Avaliação</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($indicators as $indicator): ?>
<?php echo "<tr>
    <td>". $indicator->indicator_name ."</td>
    <td>". $indicator->weight*100 ."%</td>
    <td>
        <label>
            1 <input value='1' name='score[".$indicator->id."]' type='radio'>
        </label>
        <label>
            2 <input value='2' name='score[".$indicator->id."]' type='radio'>
        </label>
        <label>
            3 <input value='3' name='score[".$indicator->id."]' type='radio'>
        </label>
        <label>
            4 <input value='4' name='score[".$indicator->id."]' type='radio'>
        </label>
        <label>
            5 <input value='5' name='score[".$indicator->id."]' type='radio'>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>";
endforeach; ?>
```

After form submit you can receive like this on another php script:

```
 echo $_POST['score'][$indicator->id];
```

Comment: Yes it works. I need to take a break. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 2):

Use `$indicator->indicator_name` instead of a number then. Any unique identifier will do, so long as it is unique for the row.